# How to improve Naive Bayes?

Tags: classification, naive-bayes-classifier, ngrams

I am solving a problem that address this question "What are the Actions that lead to high or low score?"

I have the following Data that consist of text and score , I want to derive the words or Actions from text that lead to high/low score

I have huge data , and text length can be a paragraph, sample data like below

```
+----------------------+-------+
|         Text         | Score |
+----------------------+-------+
| Support Team Goal    |    90 |
| Generate Lead        |    80 |
| Contact 30 customers |    30 |
| Support Team Goal    |    30 |
+----------------------+-------+
```

Approach followed:
I followed Naive Bayes way.

1. First I classified my Data into High (score(75 and above)) and Low (score below 75)
2. I converted the High to Term Document Matrix and the Low as well
3. **I found words appearing only in low** and judge they lead to low score (include word if frequency greater than 7 lets say)
4. **I found words appearing only in high** and judge they lead to high score (include word if frequency greater than 7 lets say in high)
5. **I found probability of common words,** For words appearing in both high or low, I calculated the probability of the word occurrence to happen in low/high (include word if probability greater than 75%)

Note: I worked with bigrams. Not sure if this is the right approach to analyze my problem, or there are better techniques. Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the actual data, all we can really do is second guess and suggest best practices. Here are some pointers you can pursue -

- **Gather more data** - If it can be done, nothing like it.
- **Improve data quality** - *The algorithm will always be as good as the data*. Try extensive cleaning methods like -
- Lowercase (basic) so all your data is standardized
- [Stemming / Lemmatization](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) - These techniques reduces a word to its root form
- Try [parts of speech tagging (POS)](https://machinelearningblogs.com/2016/12/01/opinion-mining-beyond-sentiment-analysis/) and retain important parts of speech like nouns and look at their overall importance
- Stopword removal - Just like you tried doing word frequencies, there are popular word sets like the word *the* that don't help much. They are filtered out
- [Correcting Spelling mistakes](https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) - If you are expecting there will be spelling mistakes, might be a good idea to correct them
- **Converting the unstructured data** - I see that you have used bigrams. Try using unigrams and trigrams as well, or in combinations, run your algorithm and see which one works better. Try `CountVectorizer`, `TfidfVectorizer` and other techniques like word embeddings as well
- **Algorithms** - Finally focus on the algorithm itself. For Naive Bayes, focus on [MultinomialNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html). Try [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)and other ensemble family algorithms. Try Deep Learning techniques with [keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-text-data-deep-learning-keras/). Fine tune hyperparameters based on the validation results

Of course, there are other best practices like splitting your data into `train`, `test` and `cross validation` sets. Evaluating the right metrics such as `accuracy`, `precision`, `recall` and the `confusion matrix`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a question about the algorithm part. Since most algorithms are used to predict. I am not interested in predicting the score if a new Text comes in. I'm interested in knowing what i have in my existing data, that will lead to high or low score. so is there any algorithms i can use for that?